# How to removed repeated elements from lists in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm having some problems in prolog... again
I need to make a function that receives three lists:
   elementsToRemove
   fullList
   nonRepeatedElements
The function should be this as follows:

```
removeRepeatedElements(elementsToRemove, fullList, nonRepeatedElements)
```

where nonRepeatedElements is a list without any element that is in elementsToRemve AND fullList.
Can anyone please help! Kind of desperate over here. ahah

Comment: you want to get the union of unique elements ?
i.e: func([1,2,3],[3,4,5],L).
L = [1,2,4,5] ?

Comment: no, func([1,2,3,4], [2,3], L). L=[1, 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWI-Prolog has [subtract](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subtract/3)(+Set, +Delete, -Result).

It's implemented in this way:

```
%%  subtract(+Set, +Delete, -Result) is det.
%
%   Delete all elements from `Set' that   occur  in `Delete' (a set)
%   and unify the  result  with  `Result'.   Deletion  is  based  on
%   unification using memberchk/2. The complexity is |Delete|*|Set|.
%
%   @see ord_subtract/3.

subtract([], _, []) :- !.
subtract([E|T], D, R) :-
    memberchk(E, D), !,
    subtract(T, D, R).
subtract([H|T], D, [H|R]) :-
    subtract(T, D, R).
```

You can use that implementation in any other Prolog...

Answer (score 0):

ok , according to your description , this would be the answer :

```
% base case
sto([],L,[]).

% item isn't found in the other list
sto([H|T],L,[H|T2]):-
\+member(H,L),sto(T,L,T2).

% item is present in the other list
sto([H|T],L,N):-
member(H,L),sto(T,L,N).

member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]):-
member(X,T).
```

so , `sto` is the main function , `member` function checks if the element is present in the given list

Comment: Here's the thing: I used the function `tab` to create a list with theses elements:
`tab([(top,left),(top,middle),(top,right),(center,left),(center,middle),(center,right),(bottom,left),(bottom,middle),(bottom,right)]).` 
This: `tab(AllPositions)`should create the list above with the name AllPositions right?
And I'm given this: 
`[(top, middle), (top, right), (center, middle), (center, right), 
      (bottom, middle), (bottom, right)]`
I'm supposed to eliminate the list I'm given from the list AllPositions and get a NewList without the repeated elements.

Comment: the code I wrote above works for single elements (int,char,string,etc,etc) , according to the last comment you'd have to customize it to work for tuples of 2 elements instead of 1 element..